# Drupal Tagadelic: creating my own block

Tags: drupal

Tagadelic outputs the content I need but I'm unable to apply the required design with the standard markup it outputs. I need add some markup to get rounded corners and a few other other changes need to be made.

Could some broadly explain how I'd go about this? I know I shouldn't mess with the module itself, so should I override some of its functions to output my markup?

[Here is a list of all the tagadelic functions](http://api.lullabot.com/tagadelic_build_weighted_tags) but I fail to see where the markup comes from exactly.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason you need custom markup? If you must have rounded corners can't you just do it with a custom CSS file?

Comment: I'm also using panels and this ads tons of markup. Also the design was sliced without keeping Drupal HTML in mind. I'd prefer changing the markup than altering the css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Drupal blocks support plenty of CSS customization:

`<div id="block-tagadelic-1" class="block block-tagadelic block-title block-odd">`

If the available HTML source is not sufficient for your styling needs, you could override the tagadelic theme function responsible for HTML output. It is in `tagadelic.module` on `Line 308`. Look for `function theme_tagadelic_weighted($terms)`.

Remember when overriding this function that it will not override the block theming I explained above. Also, if you do override it in this way, any update to the tagadelic module will not include this modification.

As such, you may want to create the overridden theme function in it's entirety in your theme itself: [Theme Function Overriding](http://drupal.org/node/240831)

Comment: thanks Grayside. I created a function bib_tagadelic_weighted($terms) where bib is the name of my theme and the content comes out as I want.